# How do I use TTTAttributedLabel to add "Read more"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, text, uilabel, tttattributedlabel

I have to display a small portion of a long text in objective C.how we will use TTTAttributedLabel to add a Read More button to display all text.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

- Use attributedTruncationToken to set the ".. Read more" at the end of the label.
- Set an attributed string with a link such as `NSLinkAttributeName`: `[NSURL URLWithString:EXTagURL]`.

Then use the delegate method below to navigate to the URL of the attributed string you set.

```
-(void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label
  didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url{}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure you have updated cocoapods
In your terminal:-
gem install cocoapods ,
pod install

Then set the label to class TTTAttributed label in your storyboard.
Then create an outlet to your view controller 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet TTTAttributedLabel *articleDetail;

Then create an attributed string
in viewdidload

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Read More .."];
[attributedString addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value: [NSURL URLWithString:@""] range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
self.articleDetail.attributedTruncationToken = attributedString;
```

Then finally create delegate method

```
-(void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label
didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url
{
}
```